# How to pass any object from activity to service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to pass object of "BluetoothDevice" class from an activity to service. I am getting syntaxes for passing Strings or any primitive types but not passing objects. Please Help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: http://hmkcode.com/android-passing-java-object-another-activity/

Comment: u can use https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ @praveen gupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create a class containing your data to be passed and extend that from `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and then you can put an object of that class as an `Extra` to your `Intent` and use it in your `Service`

EDIT :
as rom4ek mentioned, `BluetoothDevice` is already implements `Parcelable` and all you have to do is :

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("data", yourBluetoothDeviceObject);
yourIntent.putExtra(b);
```

and for retrieving data :

```
Bundle b = yourIntent.getExtra();
BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) b.getParcelable("data");
```

Comment: Note, that `BluetoothDevice` is already implements `Parcelable`, so all you need is just putExtra. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html

Comment: Thanx both of u, yeah @rom4ek we are not even require to create instance of bundle. I did like this and working fine.


Sender Activity - startConnectionService.putExtra("MyClass", deviceToConnect);


Receiver Service - BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra("MyClass");

Answer (score 0):

You can make your complex object implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and then you can pass it to Service using `putExtra(String name, Serializable value)` or `putExtra(String name, Parcelable value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("key", yourObject);
yourIntent.putExtra(b);
```

other hand

```
Bundle b = yourIntent.getExtra();
YourObjectType OBJ = (YourObjectType ) b.getParcelable("key");
```