# keep the service running with the same parameters

Tags: android, android-service

I pass value to the service like this

```
MyService.user = new ChatUser(task.getResult().getUser().getUid(),task.getResult().getUser().getDisplayName(), task.getResult().getUser().getEmail(), password, true, "");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MyService.class);
                        startService(intent);
```

When destroying the application the service keeps running with flag `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` but the user that I passed it becomes null

How to keeps the value from returning to null

Comment: don't store it in a static field

Comment: `I pass value to the service like this` - you don't pass anything to your service.

Comment: @TimCastelijns if i dont store in static i cant pass it

Comment: @MarkKeen i do like this `MyService.user = new ChatUser(task.getResult().getUser().getUid(),task.getResult().getUser().getDisplayName(), task.getResult().getUser().getEmail(), password, true, "");`
before I call startservice()

Comment: You're creating a `static class variable` and as such belongs to the class, not the instance of the `service`. you need to 1) make sure your  `ChatUser` class implements `Parcelable` interface 2) create a local `ChatUser` object in your `Activity` 3) create a `Bundle` add your `ChatUser` object as a `parcelable` object (including a key) 4) add the bundle to the intent then start your service - You can then retrieve the bundle in the service. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27309167/4252352

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiating wrong the service. The right steps are:

1. Create an intent and add the required values to it, like this:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
       intent.putExtra("uid_key", task
               .getResult()
               .getUser()
               .getUid());
       intent.putExtra("display_name_key", task
               .getResult()
               .getUser()
               .getDisplayName()));
       startService(intent);
   ```
2. In the your service:

   ```
   .
   .
   .

   ChatUser myChatUser;

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       if (intent.getExtras() != null){
           String uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid_key");
           String displayName = intent.getStringExtra("display_name_key");

           if (uid !=null && displayName != null){
               myChatUser = new ChatUser(uid, displayName);
           }
       }


       return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
   }
   }
   ```